# How to dynamically load a custom component in nativescript?

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript, custom-component

I am new to nativescript, and I am trying to dynamically load a custom component when I tap on button,
But I get this error:

> Error: Module 
>   '/data/data/org.nativescript.DMMobileApp01/files/app/components' not 
>   found for element 'components:Test'  com.tns.NativeScriptException:
>   Failed to find module:
>   "/data/data/org.nativescript.DMMobileApp01/files/app/components", >
>   relative to: app//

I have searched a lot but most issues and tutorials that related to dynamically load a custom component are around angular and webpack.

This function which responsible to dynamic loading of the custom component:

```
function toSettings(args){
    const page = args.object.page;
    const mainScene = page.getViewById('mainScene'); 
    let settingsCompo = builder.load({
        path: '~/components',
        name: 'test'
    });
}
```

And this is the app/components/test.xml file

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
    <Label text="yaaaay!" textWrap="true" />
</StackLayout>
```

I expect it is an easy task but I don't know why I am getting this error! Where is my missing part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved with the same code by just upgrading from nativescript version 5 to version 6

Answer (score 2):

NativeScript 6.0 makes the Webpack workflow the only one to follow. So check if you're including your component in the bundle. Since Webpack uses static analysis in order to detect what to include - it can't detect that builder.load call over there. Try using dynamic imports to tell Webpack to include the files you need.

On the other hand it seems that you're just trying to show a Settings page? In that case you might be better off just navigating to it:

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/frame#basic-navigation

Comment: If you still like to use builder, then either adjust your webpack config to bundle the XML file Or assign the XML string to a variable and pass same to the builder function.

Comment: @Bundyo actually, I use nativescript 5.4.2 version I will upgrade it and try with your recommendations and come back again